# How to delete a comma from every line of a file except the last line?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I would like to delete a comma from every line in a txt file except the last line, i have used `grep -Po '.*(?=,$)` and `sed -e 's/.$//'` but this will delete the last line because It did not contain a comma(this is my understanding).
An example:

```
1,
2,
3

using the commands above , the result will be:
1
2
```

and not :

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: `sed 's/,$//'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following :

```
sed 's/,$//'
```

It assumes no trailing whitespace and deletes a comma from the end of the line. If there's no comma, it leaves the line unmodified.

If there might be trailing whitespaces which you would like removed, the following should work with GNU sed :

```
sed -r 's/,\s*$//'
```

If you need portability, the following should work on any POSIX-compliant system :

```
sed 's/,[[:space:]]*$//'
```

---

Your `grep` command didn't work because it explicitely matched data followed by a comma and the end of the line, so the lines without comma weren't matched.
You could have fixed that by matching data followed either by a comma and the end of the line, or directly the end of the line :

```
grep -Po '.*(?=,?$)
```

I tend to dislike the use of lookarounds when an simpler implementation is possible so I would avoid this solution, but that might just be me.

---

Your `sed` command didn't work for another reason : it removed the last character of a line, whatever this character was. So with your example, in the third line the character was `3`, which when removed left the line empty.

Comment: Pretty sure BSD sed doesn't recognise `\s`

Comment: @123 very possible, I just remembered the use of `-E` instead of `-r` ; I guess I'll just document GNU sed

Comment: `[[:space:]]` is POSIX compliant

Comment: @123 Yeah, but it's also a pain to remember and write :-/

Comment: @123 Still, it was a good idea to mention and I included it in my answer, thanks

Comment: thanks a lot actually my code is a JSON output so it won't contain a white space. also the same I wanna delete a double qoute at the big and end of a line any idea? or I sould edit the content?

Comment: @Foudel You should use a JSON parser, not sed.

Comment: well the whole flow is like this:
getting all environ variables with CF env app name
then do clean up and then store the result in a file 
map the results to the new app...
any recommendation

Comment: @Foudel use `jq` probably. You can use it to parse JSON from your shell and transform it into plain text formatted as you need (or JSON of course)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Replace the , at the end in all lines except the last line ($).

```
 sed '$ ! s/,$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Command `tr -d [:punct:] < file.txt` delete all punctuation characters from file.txt